# Snake game implemented in PyGame and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I know there's already a whole bunch of similar attempts at this and I've looked at a few of them to get some tips. My main aim with this was not to write anything fancy. I wanted to create a simple game with the most basic functionality but write it really well. In other words I'm more interested in making my code professional, efficient and of high quality. One way I've tried to do this is to keep the main function simple and use it mostly for initialisation and the game loop, whilst implementing most of the functionality in separate classes and functions. Also, I would appreciate any advice on comments and docstrings because I'm sure mine are far from perfect. I also noticed the clock speed is around 4.5 GHz while playing this, so I think this could definitely do with an efficiency boost.

````
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame as pg
from random import randint

# Define window parameters
BLOCK_SIZE = 20
WIN_SIZE = 500


class Head():
    blue = (0, 0, 255)  # Colour of snake
    start_params = (BLOCK_SIZE * 0.05, BLOCK_SIZE * 0.05,
                    BLOCK_SIZE * 0.9, BLOCK_SIZE * 0.9)

    def __init__(self, pos):
        """Head of snake"""
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.last_x = self.x
        self.last_y = self.y
        self.direction = [0, -BLOCK_SIZE]
        self.square = None

    def make_block(self):
        """
        Create a surface to contain a square
        Draw a square Rect object onto said surface
        """
        self.square = pg.Surface((BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE), pg.SRCALPHA)
        # Draw a square onto the "square" surface
        pg.draw.rect(self.square, self.blue, self.start_params)

    def update_pos(self):
        """Last coords are used to update next block in the snake"""
        self.last_x = self.x
        self.last_y = self.y
        self.x += self.direction[0]
        self.y += self.direction[1]

    def change_direction(self, new_dir):
        """Change direction of snake without allowing it to go backwards"""
        if new_dir == 'u' and self.direction != [0, BLOCK_SIZE]:
            self.direction = [0, -BLOCK_SIZE]
        elif new_dir == 'd' and self.direction != [0, -BLOCK_SIZE]:
            self.direction = [0, BLOCK_SIZE]
        elif new_dir == 'l' and self.direction != [BLOCK_SIZE, 0]:
            self.direction = [-BLOCK_SIZE, 0]
        elif new_dir == 'r' and self.direction != [-BLOCK_SIZE, 0]:
            self.direction = [BLOCK_SIZE, 0]

    def check_collision(self, pos_list):
        """Check if snake collides with wall or itself"""
        if self.x in (0, WIN_SIZE) or self.y in (0, WIN_SIZE):
            return True

        if (self.x, self.y) in pos_list[3:]:
            return True

        return False

    def get_pos(self):
        return (self.last_x, self.last_y)


class Block(Head):
    def __init__(self, next_block):
        """Body of snake"""
        self.next = next_block
        pos = next_block.get_pos()
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.last_x = self.x
        self.last_y = self.y
        self.ready = 0

    def update_pos(self):
        """Use position of next block in snake to update current position"""
        self.last_x = self.x
        self.last_y = self.y
        next_pos = self.next.get_pos()
        self.x = next_pos[0]
        self.y = next_pos[1]


def add_block(snake_arr):
    """Extend snake by adding a snake block to the snake array"""
    snake_arr.append(Block(snake_arr[-1]))
    snake_arr[-1].make_block()

    return snake_arr


def check_keypress(input_event, block_object):
    """
    Take input event and change direction if arrow key
    or quit game if esc key or other exit signal
    """
    if input_event.type == pg.QUIT:
        return True
    elif input_event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
        if input_event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
            return True
        elif input_event.key == pg.K_UP:
            block_object.change_direction('u')
        elif input_event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
            block_object.change_direction('d')
        elif input_event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
            block_object.change_direction('l')
        elif input_event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
            block_object.change_direction('r')

    return False


class Food():
    def __init__(self):
        """Food block, created in the same way as a snake block"""
        self.exists = False
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.square = None

    def add_food(self):
        """If no food present, create a new food block with random position"""
        if self.exists is False:
            # Create a surface to contain a square
            self.square = pg.Surface((BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE), pg.SRCALPHA)
            # Draw a square onto the "square" surface
            pg.draw.rect(self.square, (255, 0, 0),
                         (BLOCK_SIZE * 0.05, BLOCK_SIZE * 0.05,
                          BLOCK_SIZE * 0.9, BLOCK_SIZE * 0.9))

            self.x = randint(1, (WIN_SIZE - BLOCK_SIZE)/BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE
            self.y = randint(1, (WIN_SIZE - BLOCK_SIZE)/BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE
            self.exists = True

    def check_if_eaten(self, snake):
        """If snake head is in food block, food is eaten"""
        snake_x, snake_y = snake[0]
        if (self.x <= snake_x <= self.x + BLOCK_SIZE * 0.9) and (self.y <= snake_y <= self.y + BLOCK_SIZE * 0.9):
            self.exists = False
            return True

        return False


def main():
    # Initialise PyGame
    pg.init()

    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    size = (WIN_SIZE, WIN_SIZE)  # Size of window, (width, height)
    black = (0, 0, 0)  # Background colour of window

    # Place head of snake in centre of window
    start_coord = (WIN_SIZE / 2) - (BLOCK_SIZE / 2)

    # Create window
    screen = pg.display.set_mode(size)

    head = Head([start_coord, start_coord])
    head.make_block()

    # Make first three blocks of snake
    snake = []
    snake.append(head)
    snake = add_block(snake)
    snake = add_block(snake)

    ticker = 0
    game_over = False
    food = Food()
    # Game loop
    while game_over is False:
        # Run game at 60 FPS
        clock.tick(60)
        # Monitor events and check for keypresses
        for event in pg.event.get():
            game_over = check_keypress(event, head)
        if game_over is True:
            continue

        snake_pos = [block.get_pos() for block in snake]
        game_over = head.check_collision(snake_pos)

        # Update snake position every 4 frames
        if ticker == 3:
            for s in snake:
                s.update_pos()
            ticker = 0
        ticker += 1

        food.add_food()
        eaten = food.check_if_eaten(snake_pos)
        if eaten is True:
            snake = add_block(snake)

        # Clear the window before the next frame
        screen.fill(black)
        # Draw block to window
        screen.blit(food.square, [food.x, food.y])
        for s in snake:
            screen.blit(s.square, [s.x, s.y])
        # Swap buffers
        pg.display.flip()

    pg.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```
````

Comment: _the clock speed is around 4.5 GHz_ - That's not a very useful measurement of CPU occupation. Instead, check the OS-reported CPU load percentage.

Comment: The total CPU load percentage stays well under 10%, though the temperature and power rise considerably. Not to the point where the fans get noisy but more than I expected from such a simple program. I'm running an i9-9980HK if that helps clarify anything.

Comment: In theory, to accommodate for auto-scaling CPUs, you would want to measure operations per second, which is a linear factor of frequency and user-time percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unpacking arguments

This:

```
    self.x = pos[0]
    self.y = pos[1]
```

can be

```
self.x, self.y = pos
```

One advantage of the latter is that it will catch weird sequences that have more than two items. The easier thing to do is simply have a uniform representation of coordinates, and use `x,y` everywhere instead of a random mixture of tuples and individual variables.

### Type hints

```
def __init__(self, pos):
    """Head of snake"""
    self.x = pos[0]
    self.y = pos[1]
    self.last_x = self.x
    self.last_y = self.y
    self.direction = [0, -BLOCK_SIZE]
    self.square = None
```

can likely be

```
def __init__(self, pos: Tuple[int, int]):
    """Head of snake"""
    self.x: int = pos[0]
    self.y: int = pos[1]
    self.last_x: int = self.x
    self.last_y: int = self.y
    self.direction: Tuple[int, int] = (0, -BLOCK_SIZE)
    self.square: pg.Surface = None
```

### Strongly-typed direction

Do not represent a direction as a `u/d/l/r` string. Either represent it as an enum, or a unit vector of `x,y in {(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)}`.

### Mystery position list

`pos_list[3:]:` is spooky. It's not really a good idea to assign specific meanings to elements of a list such that you need to slice it for your business logic. What do the first three positions of the snake mean? Since they have a separate meaning, does it even make sense to keep them in the same list?

### Magic constants

```
    if ticker == 3:
```

should have its constant pulled out, so that you can write

```
    if ticket == UPDATE_FRAMES - 1:
```

Comment: Thank you for your review Reinderien, I have added these improvements and significantly tidied up the `change_direction` method. Regarding the `pos_list[3:]:` line, I've figured it out and changed it to `pos_list[1:]`, which hopefully isn't seemingly cryptic anymore. The reason this couldn't have worked before is because in the list of positions, I was storing the last position of every block. Since the 3 starting blocks are initialised in the same place, the body blocks' current coordinates would be the same as the head block's last coordinates. Hence, the game would quit immediately.

Comment: So to fix this, I renamed `get_pos` to `get_last_pos` and added a `get_current_pos` method. This way, the head block can safely check the current coordinates of the body blocks, without quitting the game straight away. Then the index of `1` is simply because it doesn't make sense for the head to intersect itself, it just needs to check the rest of the body.